# How to prevent backspace symbols in input?

Tags: angular

I have done this directive in Angular 2 to prevent backspace symbols in input field if they are less 3:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[limitTo]'
})
export class RestrictInputDirective {

  @Input() limitTo: number;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(evt: KeyboardEvent) {
    let a = (evt.target as HTMLInputElement).value.length;
    if (a <= this.limitTo) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

But it does not work for me.

Using:

```
<input type="text" limitTo="5">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keyDown.backspace pseudo event to prevent backspace

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appLimitTo]'
})
export class LimitToDirective {
  @Input('appLimitTo') limitTo: number=5;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
  @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(evt: KeyboardEvent) {
   console.log(evt.target.value);
    let a = (evt.target as HTMLInputElement).value.length; 
     if (a <= this.limitTo) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }

  }
}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/back-space

Comment: Problem is on this line: `` console.log(evt.target.value); ``

Comment: change the code into  console.log(evt.target['value']); like this